# Pedaling during cycling is recored as steps in Apple Health

Tags: health.app, health-kit

I’m confused about how steps get recorded in Apple Health. I thought that HealthKit was either smart, or apps recording to HealthKit had some way of tagging input, so that things didn’t get "double booked"; but when I cycle using [my workout app](http://www.workoutdoors.net), my Watch and iPhone record steps too, so that my pedaling is recorded as steps in Apple Health (though not in the Activity app) in addition to my cycling.

Is this an HK bug, or is there something my activity app should be doing when it records cycling (e.g telling HK to disregard any steps it thinks it sees)?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this has never happened before. E.g., if when I've used other apps in the past to record an activity, HK doesn’t get confused and no steps are recorded for my pedaling.

Comment: Does this happen when you use the built in Workouts app?